# There are many numeral systems. Why do we only use the $0-9$ Hindu-Arabic numeral system?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, math-history

Here is a list of other systems:

- Babylonian numerals
- Egyptian numerals
- Aegean numerals
- May numerals
- Chinese numerals

These system are far older than the current system. How did it get to be known and used internationally by nearly every cultures these days?

Comment: I think a good answer will be rather long. Perhaps you should instead seek *reference materials* (books and articles) on the subject.

Comment: that be a a lot of reading.

Comment: This is probably better suited for the History of Math & Science Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @ritwik The Mayan system used a modified base-20 system and the Babylonians a legitimate base-60 system (their smallest place values have an element of "Roman numeral-ness" due to the use of only two atomic symbols), but those two at least are considerably more sophisticated than Roman numerals.

Comment: @pjs36: The Babylonian system had one serious drawback: they had no analogue of the decimal point (or comma). It’s as if our $15$ could represent $0.15,1.5, 15, 150$, etc. The Maya system, so far as I know, was modified only when used for the calendrical Long Count and was otherwise genuinely vigesimal.

Comment: @ritwiksinha: The Chinese number system is not really like Roman numerals.  It's essentially place-based, but with each place tagged by its power-of-$10$ value (except for the ones place).  For instance, $27183$ would be 二萬七千一百八十三: literally, two-tenthousands-seven-thousands-one-hundred-eight-tens-three.  The same characters for $1$ through $9$ ($0$ is treated somewhat differently in modern spoken Chinese) are used for each place.

Comment: @BrianTung As i said i just saw the pictures and it looked to me like roman numbers, thanks for clarification. i should delete my old comment it is causing a lot of confusion.

Comment: @ritwiksinha: If you feel like it.  I didn't think it was that confusing, but the generalization is not *quite* wholly right.

Comment: History has gone that way: Medieval Europe, following Islamic culture, discarded Roman system and adopted the Hindu-Arabic numeral system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For short, positional numeral systems offer the great advantage to have efficient algorithms for the computation of sum and products, easy to use in everyday life. The base $10$ is more or less accidental (besides we having $10$ fingers, on average): for instance, there would be many efficient divisibility tests in base $60$ (since $60$ has a lot of divisors), but $60$ figures are hard to memorize, while in base $2$ "everyday numbers" tend to have too long representations. Base $10$ is a good compromise, even if base $12$ would have probably been better.

Comment: (+1) for "on average," and for mentioning that a numeric alphabet of sixty characters would be cumbersome *at best*.

Comment: Imagine learning the multiplication table in base 60, a nightmare! Also Mayan base 20 would be quite boring!

Comment: The Babylonian sexagesimal system was not at all hard to remember, it's more fair to describe it as a hybrid base combining 6 and 10, and the characters are extremely regular: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal#Babylonian_mathematics.  I still wouldn't want to be forced to memorize the base 60 multiplication table :).

Answer (score 9):

First of all, the Egyptian and Aegean systems are "agglutinative" rather than positional. I'm looking at the Unicode Aegean numbers block and I see that they have a specific symbol for ninety thousand. What if you need to represent one hundred thousand? Do you just invent a new symbol for it?

Scientists estimate the universe has $10^{80}$ particles. Wolfram Alpha tells me the next prime number after $10^{80}$ is $10^{80} + 129$. If we had some way to indicate exponents in the Aegean number system, we would be able to express both these numbers with that system. But both the Aegean and Egyptian systems are inherently handicapped.

The Babylonian numerals don't have that limitation, but the choice of base is a little unwieldy. And the Europeans didn't even know about the Mayans until after Columbus thought he had discovered a shortcut to India, so the practicality of their system (or lack thereof) was moot.

That leaves the Chinese numerals, and I think the Europeans knew about the Chinese before they knew about the Mayans. But could they use a system that was so intrinsically tied to the Chinese language? Even today I would doubt that.

So as a result of circumstance, we have the Hindu-Arabic numeral system as our primary system of numeration. But do give credit to the Romans: we still use their numerals for some things even today.

Answer (score 3):

For some history of the Hindu-Arabic system, see e.g. [this article](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/HistTopics/Indian_numerals.html) and [this article](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/HistTopics/Arabic_numerals.html).
This system was introduced to Europe in the Middle Ages: one of the early influential texts was "Liber abaci" by [Fibonacci](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Fibonacci.html).  See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Hindu%E2%80%93Arabic_numeral_system#Adoption_in_Europe).